# Getting columns with the same name from different Mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for comments ("event_comments") to different events with the following columns:

- post_id
- event_id
- username
- comment
- date

I want to be able to retrieve this info from the database and also be able to print the username, first name and last name; for this, I thought of using INNER JOIN, but it is not working for the following reason: I have 3 different profile types (3 different tables) "students", "guardians", "teachers" and when I try to use the INNER JOIN using "username" I get an error message saying that Column 'username' in from clause is ambiguous.

```
SELECT event_comments.post_id, event_comments.event_id, event_comments.username, event_comments.comment, event_comments.date, 
students.first_name, students.last_name, students.picture, 
guardians.first_name, guardians.last_name, guardians.picture, 
teachers.first_name, teachers.last_name, teachers.picture 
FROM event_comments 
INNER JOIN students 
INNER JOIN guardians 
INNER JOIN teachers 
USING (username) 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

I tried to do this and it worked, but it only shows 1 comment per user; if the user has more than 1 comment then the info is ignored:

```
SELECT event_comments.post_id, event_comments.event_id, event_comments.username, event_comments.comment, event_comments.date, 
students.first_name, students.last_name, students.picture, 
guardians.first_name, guardians.last_name, guardians.picture, 
teachers.first_name, teachers.last_name, teachers.picture 
FROM event_comments 
INNER JOIN students 
INNER JOIN guardians 
INNER JOIN teachers 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Does anybody how to get the INNER JOINs to work? is there a better way to do what I want? I hope I explained myself well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
 SELECT event_comments.post_id, event_comments.event_id, event_comments.username, event_comments.comment, event_comments.date, 
    students.first_name, students.last_name, students.picture, 
    guardians.first_name, guardians.last_name, guardians.picture, 
    teachers.first_name, teachers.last_name, teachers.picture 
    FROM event_comments 
    INNER JOIN students
    on event_comments.username=students.username 
    INNER JOIN guardians 
    on event_comments.username=guardians.username 
    INNER JOIN teachers
    on event_comments.username=teachers.username  
    ORDER BY date DESC 
    LIMIT 20
```

This will work but assuming that a username from one table is not present in other tables, this will result into 0 rows.

a more logical approach would be to select each table then union it to join every result set like this :

```
SELECT e.post_id, e.event_id, e.username, e.comment, e_comments.date, 
    s.first_name, s.last_name, s.picture
    from event_comments e
    inner join students s 
    on e.username=g.username
UNION SELECT e.post_id, e.event_id, e.username, e.comment, e_comments.date, 
    g.first_name, g.last_name, g.picture
    from event_comments e
    inner join guardians g
    on e.username=g.username
UNION SELECT e.post_id, e.event_id, e.username, e.comment, e_comments.date, 
    t.first_name, t.last_name, t.picture
    from event_comments e
    inner join teacher t
    on e.username=t.username
```

EDIT:
To explain better about the query it just does this simple steps:

1. Query all comments from students using username to join post to students
2. Query all comments from guardians using username to join post to guardians
3. Query all comments from teachers using username to join post to teachers
4. Join results from students,guardians, teachers together

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is what I end up getting: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). This is so confusing. I am starting to think that maybe it is not possible to do what I want to do.

Comment: this is almost exactly what I need. Thanks a lot. I have to study your answer because it is so complicated for a newbie like me. I wish I could post a picture so that you can see what's coming up... What is happening is that it is showing the results duplicated, half of the results are good, but the other half has "NULL" in the following fields first_name, last_name, and picture... I am trying to figure out why, but I can't...

Comment: Yes it would be best if i could see your result set so i can see whats wrong. Problem is probably within your data

Comment: Oops my bad. Was using left join. Try again null values and duplicates should disappear. Also added explanation to query so you can understand it better :) But its good to note that optimization wise this is not good since you are querying the database 3 times then add the fact that it needs to join the result set. Redesigning your tables to make it only 1 and just add a column for user type would be your best option

Comment: That did it! THANKS A LOT! I am going to study the answer carefully to understand it better. So, you recommend to have just 1 table, the problem is that there are some fields that do not apply to the other 2 profile types... should I just try to leave the default value of those columns as 0 then? I thought that having different tables was a better option..

Answer (score 1):

You need the `using` clause for each pair of `join`s:

```
FROM event_comments INNER JOIN
     students 
     USING (username) INNER JOIN
     guardians 
     USING (username) INNER JOIN
     teachers 
     USING (username)
```

In MySQL, an `inner join` with no `on` clause is treated as a `cross join`.  In other databases, an `on` or `using` clause is required for an `inner join`.

Comment: The query works, but this is what I get: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Comment: @Rookie then make them left joins.. since you are filtering out all rows

Comment: @Rookie . . . Then `username` is not the right join key for the tables.  You need to use the correct key.

Comment: @Rookie Using left joins will work but it will result into alot of null columns which you dont need. Alternatively you can use a union select. check my answer bellow

Comment: @JohnRuddell nope now that i think about it left joins wont work as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff in your query, username has to be present in student,guardians and teacher tables at the same time to give out a result. Which obviously the reason he is not getting any results from his query as well.

Comment: @TheProvost . . . If you look at the answer that was accepted, the same column is in all the tables.

Comment: Yes the answer that was accepted was mine and the column username is present in all tables. Only difference is im not joining students to guardians or guardians to teachers which you are doing with your query. That is why i mentioned to you that in order for your query to result anything is for a username "row" to be present on all 4 tables. Review on what "Inner Join" is for